# I can't add the Time.deltatime for jump script for framerate independent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The

```
rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;
```

works  but I want to add the `Time.DeltaTime` to code. Like this:

```
rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity*Time.deltaTime;
```

when I add it a character, it does not jump despite the fact I use the `Rigidbody2D gravity` and the dynamic character.

**FULL CODE:**

```
public float MovementSpeed = 1;
private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2D;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    boxCollider2D = transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
    var movementUp = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (IsGrounded() && movementUp > 0)
    {
        float jumpVelocity = 1000f;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{
   float extraHeightText = 1f;
   RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2D.bounds.center, boxCollider2D.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, extraHeightText , layerMask);
   return raycastHit2D.collider != null;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). why do you want to include `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: because i am planing to make multiplayer game. I want to use it for smooth frame flow between 2 players. If ı can add it jumping animation will be simultaneous between 2 android phone. i can prevent delay problem of animations

Comment: I'm sorry but to me that doesn't seem to be related to multiplying a velocity assignment by `Time.deltaTime `. Can you describe the observed problem when you use `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity;`?

Comment: I found solution. I shoudnt use * time.deltatime for velocity. because jumpvelocity making it framerate independent. Actually ı wanted to provide framerate independent. jumpvelocity already moves my character at a speed that is framerate independent, using Time.deltaTime actually breaks things. It basically becomes framerate dependent again due to my velocity essentially being speed * Time.deltaTime * Time.deltaTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I shoudnt use * time.deltatime for velocity. because jumpvelocity making it framerate independent. Actually ı wanted to provide framerate independent. jumpvelocity already moves my character at a speed that is framerate independent, using Time.deltaTime actually breaks things. It basically becomes framerate dependent again due to my velocity essentially being speed * Time.deltaTime * Time.deltaTime.